# Simultaneous Equation In 3 Variable Using Substitution Method

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve this linear equation but I am getting wrong solution.

> $$4x-3y+z=-1 \tag1$$
>   $$x+5y-z=12 \tag2$$  $$2y+z=10\tag3$$

I tried substituting $z = 10-2y$ and $x = 12+2/5y$ the answer I did not get
I tried solving the both the equation putting the value to first equation.

Comment: You can put $z=10-2y$ in the second equation then isolate $x$ in terms of $y$. Finally subtitue both results in the first equation.

Comment: How do yo get this $x=12+2/5y$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the substitution of $z$,

$$4x-5y=-11,\\x+7y=22.$$

Then substituting $x=22-7y$,

$$-33y=-99.$$